# React.Suspense doesn't trigger a fallback when navigating to the same page with different query params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Despite the long title, the problem is actually quite simple.

I have a following loader function (I am using react-router v6):

```
import { defer, redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import store from "../globalStore/store";

function subjectsPageLoader({request} : any) {
    const state = store.getState();
    console.log(state);

    if (!state.authorization.authorized) {
        console.warn('User is not authorized: redirecting...');
        return redirect('/authorization');
    }
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const keys = url.searchParams.getAll('key');
    
    console.log(url.href);

    const worksheetsUrl = new URL('http://localhost:3002/subjects');
    for (let key of keys) {
        worksheetsUrl.searchParams.append('key', key);
    }

    // set default key
    if (keys.length === 0) {
        keys.push('2.1.');
    }

    console.log(`Preparing to fetch url = ${worksheetsUrl}`);

    return defer({
        keys,
        subjectTree: fetch('http://localhost:3002/subjectTree').then(res => res.json() ),
        worksheets: fetch(worksheetsUrl).then(res => res.json() ),
    })
}
export default subjectsPageLoader;
```

This loader kicks in whenever the URL "/subjects" is triggered (with arbitrary query params). The key thing to note is that when triggering such URL I expect some data to load asynchronously (see 'defer' in the code above).

Thus I would like to see some kind of loading while this data gets delivered - that's why I use 'React.Suspense' with a fallback along with 'Await' (as the docs https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred suggest).

The actual problem is this - when I am already at the "/subjects" URL (say, with params key=2&key=3, i.e. full path is "/subjects?key=2&key=3") I might then want to navigate to this exact URL but with different params (say, I would like to navigate to "/subjects?key=62" from currently active "/subjects?key=2&key=3").

And when I do this, the loader function still works as expected however the 'React.Suspense' doesn't show a fallback while fetching data.

Here is this part of the code with 'React.Suspense' and 'Await' (I am using Ant Design in my project):

```
<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading table...</div>}>
    <Await
      resolve={worksheets}
      errorElement={
        <div>Could not load table </div>
      }
    >
      {(resolved) => {
        console.log('Got data from sheets:');
        console.warn(resolved);
        resolved.forEach((row: any, i: number) => {
          data.push({
            key: i,
            age: row[0],

            malesFemalesAll: row[1],
            malesAll: row[2],
            femalesAll: row[3],

            malesFemalesCity: row[4],
            malesCity: row[5],
            femalesCity: row[6],

            malesFemalesRural: row[7],
            malesRural: row[8],
            femalesRural: row[9],
          });
        });
        console.log('Parsed data from sheets:');
        console.warn(data);
        return (
          <>
            <Table
              columns={columns}
              dataSource={data}
              bordered
              size="middle"
              scroll={{ x: 'calc(700px + 50%)', y: 240 }}
            />
          </>
        )
      }}
    </Await>
  </React.Suspense>
```

I can assume that the problem might be connected with the 'React.Suspense' itself, but in any case I have no idea how to fix this problem for now.

Comment: This appears to be mostly "by design". See [When does the `<Suspense />` fallback render?](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred#when-does-the-suspense-fallback-render)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Changing a route segment instead of query params actually makes React.Suspense fallback to re-render, that solves the issue.